# I want to encrypt my WordPress plugin

Tags: plugin-development, encryption

We have developed a custom WordPress plugin.

We want to encrypt the plugin code to protect the data.

The plugin file contains 2 main files - The main plugin core file and a .php file.

Both the files contains WordPress core functions as well as plugin hook functions.

I found that we can encrypt .php file using some online tool. But it shows some error because of the WordPress core functions. ie., the online tool couldn't encrypt the PHP file since it contains the WordPress core functions also.

Hence I want to know is there any other way around to encrypt my plugin files?

We don't want to spend  money to buy any tool for the encryption. Hence could you please provide me any suggestions on how to encrypt a plugin at free of cost?

Comment: If you plan on distributing this plugin then doing so would be a violation of the GPL and therefore illegal.

Comment: can i encrypt the .php file alone if it not contains any wordpress core functions?

Comment: If it's part of a WordPress plugin, I doubt it? It must be connected to the plugin somehow. Are you trying to encrypt it because it contains sensitive information? Or because you think people want to steal your code for some reason?

Comment: Yes. it is part of the wordpress plugin. I have just included the .php file inside the main plugin file using include() function.

Comment: My plugin gets the social media urls from the users ( those who installed our plugin) and stores their information in the database. It also stores their license key in the database. Other than this, there is no sensitive information.

Comment: Ok so there's no good reason to encrypt the file. Storing social media URLs is not so difficult that people are going to steal your code. If you need to protect this for commercial reasons then I'd be more worried about the dozens of free open-source plugins that already exist and do this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. But sorry to ask this again. I really want to clarify this. Even though there are free plugins available, if i want to encrypt the .php file alone if it not contains any wordpress core functions, is it possible?

Comment: No. If your application (plugin) includes GPL code (it does, in the main plugin file), then the whole thing must be distributed under GPL, which means it must be open source.

Comment: But if the bulk of your plugin really isn't using any WordPress APIs, then it's a bad plugin.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for your valuable response.

Answer (score 3):

***Can*** you encrypt your plugin files? **Yes,** ("yes" meaning that it is "possible" - **not** "permissible")

***Should*** you? **No.**

Let's start with the obvious. [WordPress is licensed under GPL](https://wordpress.org/about/license/) - GNU General Public License.

What does that mean? It means that WordPress and any derivative work needs to be "open source." In other words, the source needs to be "open," readable, and available. The interpretation as far as WordPress is concerned (linked above) is that any "derivative work" must also be GPL or GPL compatible (as not all open source licensing is compatible with GPL). **A plugin is considered "a derivative work" because it relies on WordPress to operate (it cannot run by itself), and therefore must be GPL compatible. Encrypting your code is NOT GPL compatible.**

Since there was some commentary on legality, it should be noted that encrypting your plugin files is not "illegal" in the sense that a SWAT team will kick in your door with a warrant for your arrest.  But it could result in a lawsuit (although that's unlikely).  The more likely outcome is that few users buy your plugin, since it would not be open source (I'm presuming you're looking to sell it - otherwise, why would you encrypt it in the first place).

For plugins and themes in WordPress, this debate has been something that has gone on back-and-forth for as long as I've been involved with WP (2004); and it will likely continue. But the bottom line is this - **if you encrypt or otherwise obfuscate your code, you go against everything that GPL and open source software stands for**.  The entire reason WordPress is as successful as it is is because it is open source.

If you obfuscate your code, it will certainly be rejected by wordpress.org for inclusion in the repository. It would also be rejected by any reputable aggregator (such as CodeCanyon).  Your distribution options would mostly be limited to managing it through your own site.

So to summarize, *can* you encrypt it? Yes, insofar as it is possible. But that doesn't mean you *should*. (Also, it doesn't mean you *can* from a strictly legal sense.)  If you find that you *need* to encrypt, then you shouldn't be developing something for an open source platform.

Then, the last thing you mentioned also needs to be addressed:

> We dont want to spend money to buy any tool for the encryption. Hence
>   could you please provide me any suggestions on how to encrypt a plugin
>   at free of cost?

Presumably, you're looking at this as a commercial venture - selling a plugin to a base of users.  Otherwise, why would it be necessary to obfuscate the code?

If that's the case, why would you chintz on investing in that process?  You want to commercialize your plugin, but you don't want to spend any money on it?  Quite frankly, that's absurd.  It's like a bright neon sign flashing overhead that says, "Welcome to Amateur Night."  I don't mean that to insult you, but rather to point out how it makes things look from a business perspective.

If you're going to venture out commercially, make appropriate investments in the tools you need (although that is **not** suggesting to invest in encrypting your code).

Perhaps what you really need to look at is your business model and what needs to change in order to grow and compete in a 21st Century economy.  I recommend that you read "Free: The Future of a Radical Price" by Chris Anderson to wrap your head around how you monetize something that is "free" (regardless of whether that item is "*free as in speech*" or "*free as in beer*," which is the essence of the GPL).